# input type image value display problem on the next page

Tags: php, image, input, types

(first page)

```
    <form action="page1.php" method="post"> 
     <input type="image" src="images/leavecredits.png" name="btnImage" id="btnImage" value="uuuu"/>

<input type="hidden" id="hiddenEmpID" name="hiddenEmpID" value="yyyy"/>

  <input type="image" src="images/leavecards.png" alt="Submit" width="100" height="100" style="background-color:#FFF; border:dotted #CCCCCC thin;"  onMouseOver="this.src='images/leavecards_onmouseover.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='images/leavecards.png'"  
  id="btnLeaveManagement2" name="btnLeaveManagement2" value="leavecards">   

</form>
```

(page1.php)

```
<?PHP
echo "<br>hiddenEmpID: " . $_POST['hiddenEmpID'];
echo "<br>btnImage: " . $_POST['btnImage'];
?>
```

result:

```
hiddenEmpID: yyyy
```

> Notice: Undefined index: btnImage  .... in line....

```
btnImage:
```

value of the type image input does not appear on the next page
browser: chrome and mozilla

what do you think is wrong guys?

---

(possible solution if value really does not work)
Hi guys, since i really want to try using type="image" as a button i came up with this dirty code on php

```
<form action="page1.php" method="post">
<input type="image" src="images/leavecredits.png" alt="Submit" id="btnLeaveManagement" name="btnLeaveManagement"  width="100" height="100" style="background-color:#FFF; border:dotted #CCCCCC thin;"  onMouseOver="this.src='images/leavecredits_onmouseover.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='images/leavecredits.png'" >
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenEmpID" name="hiddenEmpID" value="leavecards"/>
</form>

<form action="page1.php" method="post">
<input type="image" src="images/leavecredits.png" alt="Submit" id="btnLeaveManagement" name="btnLeaveManagement"  width="100" height="100" style="background-color:#FFF; border:dotted #CCCCCC thin;"  onMouseOver="this.src='images/leavecredits_onmouseover.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='images/leavecredits.png'" >
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenEmpID" name="hiddenEmpID" value="leavecredits"/>
</form>

    echo "<br>hiddenEmpID: " . $_POST['hiddenEmpID'];
```

---

now it will depend on hidden input's value

Answer (score 0):

The HTML spec for an image input says that it does not pass along a value.  Instead it may pass along the x and y coordinates of where you clicked on the image.  [Read more here...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/image)

Regardless if you want to use an image as a regular submit button, wrap an image inside of a form button with type submit.

```
<button type="submit" ... ><img src="image.jpg" .../></button>
```

Comment: i really want to try an image becomming a submit button mattQuest :)

Comment: if you want image then use hidden field for passing the value to the next page

Comment: button with type submit wrapped around an image does not accomplish this for you?

Comment: i already tried submit button wrapped i would just like to explore different possibilities... what i am trying to accomplish is that i have 4 input type image with different values mattQuest :)

Comment: yesterday it really work.... but now... the value is of the input type image is like as if does not exist anymore... -_-

Comment: did you read the html spec I linked you to?  input type image is not supposed to pass the value, it's doing exactly what it's supposed to do

Comment: when it worked yesterday, were you using a different browser?  (not all browsers conform to the html specs)

Comment: yes it work yesterday... chrome browser.. it work at house also... i will check later when i get home... i will update this page :) thank you mattQuest

Answer (score 0):

An input type="image" only defines that image as the submit button and not as an input that can carry over a value to the server.

Using the type="image" is problematic because the ability to pass a value is disabled for some stupid lack of reason. Anyways & although it's not as customizable & thus as pretty, you can still use your images so long as they are part of a type="button".

Please use hidden field or input type button instead of input type image.

Comment: yesterday... it work.. i created 4 input type image... with the same name... with different value.. but now it does not work anymore

Comment: using image type is not a good practice. the same name also is not working during get post value.

Comment: yeah rahul, just trying stuffs :)